# No ping between two 22.04 laptops but can ping both ways from 3rd (windows) device

Tags: networking, 22.04, routing, ping, arp

I have a subnet 192.168.100.x where all IPs a served DHCP over WiFi.
I have

- XPS laptop       192.168.100.121 (Ubuntu 22.04)
- Inspiron laptop  192.168.100.107 (Ubuntu 22.04)
- Windows laptop   192.168.100.113 (Windows 10)
- Many other devices on the same subnet

I can ping all devices & laptops from all laptops with the single exception of the XPS laptop to the Inspiron laptop and vice-versa which fails with 'Destination Host Unreachable' both ways. To be explicit:

**FROM the XPS - 192.168.100.121**

> PING 192.168.100.107 (192.168.100.107) 56(84) bytes of data. From
>
> 192.168.100.121 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
>
> ...
>
> PING 192.168.100.113 (192.168.100.113) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes
>
> from 192.168.100.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=4.26 ms

**FROM the Inspiron - 192.168.100.107**

> PING 192.168.100.121 (192.168.100.121) 56(84) bytes of data. From
>
> 192.168.100.107 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
>
> ...
>
> PING 192.168.100.113 (192.168.100.113) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes
>
> from 192.168.100.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.02 ms

**FROM the Windows laptop - 192.168.100.113**

> Pinging 192.168.100.121 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from
>
> 192.168.100.121: bytes=32 time=79ms TTL=64
>
> ...
>
> Pinging 192.168.100.107 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from
>
> 192.168.100.107: bytes=32 time=112ms TTL=64

If I do an `arp -a` on the XPS

> dlinkrouter (192.168.100.1) at 60:63:4c:7b:f6:79 [ether] on wlp59s0 ?
>
> (192.168.100.187) at 00:11:32:9c:7a:72 [ether] on wlp59s0
>
> Inspiron (192.168.100.107) at <incomplete> on wlp59s0 Windows
>
> (192.168.100.113) at d8:5d:e2:0b:22:6d [ether] on wlp59s0

If I do an `arp -a` on the Inspiron

> XPS (192.168.100.121) at <incomplete> on wlp1s0
>
> Windows (192.168.100.113) at d8:5d:e2:0b:22:6d [ether] on wlp1s0
>
> dlinkrouter (192.168.100.1) at 60:63:4c:7b:f6:79 [ether] on wlp1s0

If I do an `arp -a` on the Windows laptop

> Interface: 192.168.100.113 --- 0x14
>
> Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
>
> 192.168.100.1         60-63-4c-7b-f6-79     dynamic
>
> 192.168.100.107       60-57-18-28-48-8f     dynamic
>
> 192.168.100.121       9c-b6-d0-b7-0a-5d     dynamic
>
> 192.168.100.164       10-62-e5-bc-d6-ad     dynamic
>
> 192.168.100.187       00-11-32-9c-7a-72     dynamic
>
> 192.168.100.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
>
> 224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
>
> 224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
>
> 224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
>
> 239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
>
> 255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

I am no network engineer. Much googling suggests that I am not getting the ARP response with the MAC address in but I have no idea why it is just between the two Ubuntu systems. Lots of posts blame routers firewalls or 802.11 implementations but I think, because every other communication through the router works fine, I have ruled that out. I even set up an ssh server on the Inspiron which results in the same 'Destination Host Unreachable' from the XPS but the Windows Laptop can connect no issue.

Any ideas on where to go next?

**=========================== UPDATE 1 ============================**

I have, unsatisfactorily, fixed the issue by manually adding the IP:HWaddr pairs to the ARP caches thus:

**On the XPS - 192.168.100.121**

> sudo arp -s 192.168.100.107 60:57:18:28:48:8f

**On the Inspiron - 192.168.100.107**

> sudo arp -s 192.168.100.121 9c:b6:d0:b7:0a:5d

So I can ping both ways now. However, I do not understand why the ARP request broadcast was not being responded too in the specific instance of requests from these laptops too each other but are in all other circumstances. I will probably make these changes permanent i.e. fix the IPs and the ARP cache entry and dig some more when I have time. My line of inquiry at the moment is understanding whether my router is failing to proxy the ARP request or indeed if it needs too (both laptops are on the same WiFi network BSSID - not sure if this acts like a 'physical' network).

**=========================== UPDATE 2 ============================**

I made a startup service to do the static ARP mapping. Not ideal but I put the details [on GitHub](https://github.com/Shapedsundew9/toolbox/tree/main/ARP) in case it helps others.

**=========================== UPDATE 3 ============================**

It's the router - the internet did know what it was talking about. After much testing & many seemingly inconsistent results I narrowed it down to the router not proxying ARP requests between the 3 WiFi networks it supports 2.4GHz/5GHz A/5GHz B. My router is a Dlink DIR-3040 with 'smart-connect' which 'intelligently' puts devices on the best of the bands. I have turned off that feature and put the devices I want to connect on the same band and so far so good.